# Conditional update statement in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-update

I have a problem with building a conditional update statement in **Oracle**. For understandability, I'll simplify the problem and basically my update statement should look like this:

```
UPDATE SAMPLE_TAB1 t 
   SET t.sample_column1 =NVL(t.sample_column1, **SOME LOGIC**);
```

The `***SOME LOGIC***` part should look like this: (Please consider this is just a pseudo code)

```
IF ((SELECT sample_column2 FROM SAMPLE_TAB2 
       WHERE sample_column2= sample_value2
       AND sample_column3  = sample_value3 )='FALSE' THEN 
   t.sample_column1 =0;
ELSE

   t.sample_column1 =(SELECT sample_column1 FROM SAMPLE_TAB3 
                         WHERE sample_column4= sample_value4
                         AND sample_column5  = sample_value5 )

END IF;
```

Any kind of thoughts on this problem would be welcome. Thank you.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try the following code

```
UPDATE SAMPLE_TAB1 t 
    SET t.sample_column1 = (
      case when ((SELECT sample_column2 FROM SAMPLE_TAB2 
                          WHERE sample_column2= sample_value2 
                          AND sample_column3  = sample_value3 ) = 'FALSE' )
            then 0
      else
          (SELECT sample_column1 FROM SAMPLE_TAB3 
                         WHERE sample_column4= sample_value4
                         AND sample_column5  = sample_value5 )
      end

    )
  WHERE t.sample_column1 is not null;
```

Answer (score 1):

try the following

```
UPDATE SAMPLE_TAB1 t 
   SET t.sample_column1 = NVL( (SELECT sample_column2  FROM ...), 0)
WHERE t.sample_column1 is not null
;
```

Comment: Hi what about the SAMPLE_TAB3 related logic then